# css animation scale and rotate at same time

Tags: css, css-animations

How to run two animations at same time on one element for scalling (like zoom in) and rotate simultaneously.

I have tried that but not work

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('container').style = '-webkit-transform:scale(0) rotate(0deg);';
},1000);
  
//here I need to scale in and rotate at same time 
setTimeout(function(){

//That I have tried intitially and not woking 
//document.getElementById('container').style = '-webkit-animation : kf_scale 1s, kf_rotate 1s';

//As suggested by @Terry I have edited after to this but still not working
    document.getElementById('container').style = '-webkit-animation : kf_scale 1s';
},3000);
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes kf_scale {

100% {
 -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(360deg);
}
} 
@-webkit-keyframes kf_rotate {

100% {
 -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
}

#container{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:solid 1px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    test animation scale + rotate
</div>
```

```
//That I have tried intitially and not woking
```

document.getElementById('container').style = '-webkit-animation : kf_scale 1s, kf_rotate 1s';

```
//As suggested by @Terry I have edited after to this but still not working
```

document.getElementById('container').style = '-webkit-animation : kf_scale 1s';
    },3000);

Comment: You will have to combine the transforms (scale and rotate) into a single rule (in this case, you will need to create a new key frame for scale + rotation). Contrary to intuition, transforms do not stack. Like any other CSS properties, the last occurrence will override all that precedes it.

Comment: What mean  "combine ... into a single rule" ? some like this ? ´transform:scale(1) rotate(360deg)´

Comment: You’ve got it all figured out :) that is correct!

Comment: Thank's but not work (I have edited my snippet) ...

Comment: Do you intend to use `kf_rotate`? You aren't calling it anywhere.

Comment: Yes I have used before. I have added some explanations to the question to avoid confusions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem, you're overwriting the `style` property, so your initial `transform` is overwritten with the `animation`. So the `animation` won't s frtartom the point of the `transition`, it will start from the default style of the element. The `animation` is `scale()`ing from the default (`1`) to `1`, so it doesn't scale. To get the animation to scale from the point where the previous `transform` ended, add the properties of the `transform` to the first step of the `animation`

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('container').style = '-webkit-transform:scale(0) rotate(360deg);';
},3000);
  
//here I need to scale in and rotate at same time 
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('container').style = '-webkit-animation : kf_scale 1s';
},5000);
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes kf_scale {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-360deg);
  }
} 

#container{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:solid 1px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    test animation scale + rotate
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the following:

Your.html

```
<div class="pop"></div>
```

your.css

```
@keyframes popDiv { 
    0%   {transform: scale(1)  rotate(0deg);}
    25%  {transform: scale(2) rotate(120deg);}
    50%  {transform: scale(.5) rotate(240deg);}
    100% {transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);}
}

.pop{    
    animation: popDiv 8s alternate ease-in-out;
}
```